# How do I run CompletableFuture on a new thread in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

So I have this code that I want to run on new thread.

Let me explain better, I have 2 methods in which I want to run in parallel.

```
public String method1(){
   ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

   return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            //...
        }, pool);
} 


public String method2(){
   ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

   return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            //...
        }, pool);
}
```

So I would like to call these two methods in another method & Run them in parallel.

```
public void method3(){
 // Run both methods
 method1();
 method2();
 // end
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "this below isn't working as I thought". What isn't "working"? Do you get any errors? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @ChetanJadhavCD Please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

You method signature does not correspond to return value. When you change both methods to return CompletableFuture you can define expected behavior in `method3`:

```
CompletableFuture<String> method1Future = method1();
CompletableFuture<String> method2Future = method2();

// example of expected behavior
method1Future.thenCombine(method2Future, (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2);
```

In the example above you will concatenate strings which are supplied asynchronously by `method1` and `method2` when both futures are completed.